# No rendered annotation line on Line Chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

There is no horizontal line above the LineChart. Where am I wrong?
I'm using libraries below and parcel like bundler

```json
"chart.js": "^3.3.0",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^1.0.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
```

Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

const data = {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Line Chart',
      data: [0, 25, 45, 69, 80],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
    },
  ],
};
const line = {
  type: 'line',
  borderColor: '#FF8C00',
  borderWidth: 1,
  yMin: 50,
  yMax: 50,
};

const options = {
  annotation: {
    annotations: {
      line,
    },
  },
};

const LineChart = () => (
  <div>
    <Line className="line-chart" data={data} type="line" options={options} />
  </div>
);

export default LineChart;
```

I've tried add `plugins` object into `options` object like [here](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/samples/types/line.html).
I've tried make it like [this](https://medium.com/@Mastercoder8/chart-js-with-reactjs-43a6fdd26d86) <- it is not so outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the big red warning on the getting started page you need to register the plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/#getting-started

Instead of:

```js
import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

Import and register the plugin like so:

```js
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

Chart.register(annotationPlugin);
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc